# Rename [safe-browsing] to [google-safe-browsing]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [safe-browsing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safe-browsing) has the following excerpt:

> Safe Browsing is a service provided by Google that enables applications to check URLs against Google's constantly updated lists of suspected phishing and malware pages.

It is about the Google API, not about safe browsing in general. However, that is not how it is used. I have retagged two new questions just during the last 24 hours, and I have seen high rep users edit questions to add the tag where it does not belong. Of the 30 questions tagged, most use the tag incorrectly. Clearly the name is confusing.

**Edit and update:** The tag is still named [safe-browsing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safe-browsing), and it keeps being used where it does not belong. I took this up in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42769346), and @Avid highlighted that there are multiple products like Googles. So making it Google specific might not be the best idea.

So perhaps something like [safe-browsing-api](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safe-browsing-api) or [safe-browsing-filter](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safe-browsing-filter) would be more suitable? Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Sooo ... is this happening..?

Comment: @TomK. Usually meta questions move at a quite slow speed, which is fine because there's no hurry and it's always good to give some time for not so frequent contributors to shime in. But yeah, I hope this will be happening! If you want some action now, ping a moderator in chat. I will eventually if you don't.

Comment: @TomK. Personally I think your answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

[safe-browsing-filter](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safe-browsing-filter) has my vote for two reasons:

1. It is more accesible for new users and/or users that are not
   familiar with this topic.
2. It includes the existing solutions by Google and Mozilla and
   possible future solutions that are not API-based but have the same
   functionality.